# AWS Error creating DynamoDB table: ValidationException while creating a dynamodb table using terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am creating a dynamodb table with following schema in terraform:

[image: code in terraform]

and getting the following error:

> aws_dynamodb_table.: AWS Error creating DynamoDB table: ValidationException: 1 validation error detected: Value 'KEYS-ONLY' at 'globalSecondaryInde
> xes.1.member.projection.projectionType' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy enum value set: [ALL, INCLUDE, KEYS_ONLY]

This exception is coming from AWS. But not sure what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 3):

The error is telling you everything you need to know - it says "Member must satisfy enum value set: [ALL, INCLUDE, KEYS_ONLY]" but your enum value is `KEYS-ONLY`.  Replace this with `KEYS_ONLY`

Comment: I need to check my eyes and wear prescription glasses. Thanks!